# How to enabled internet access to an RDS instance when nat gateway is enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To enable an application behind an ELB to always use the same public IP for outbound traffic, I configured a NAT gateway.

OK, it works fine.

But now, I cannot access to the RDS instance (which is public) from the internet.

How could I enable internet access to the RDS instance ?
More, I would like to restrict public IP that access the RDS instance.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the RDS in a public subnet and was it set to public access?

Comment: no, RDS is in a private subnet. We would not like to change the architecture !

Comment: Then you can't connect to it from internet. That's the entire point of having rds in private subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Amazon RDS database is in a **private subnet**, it cannot be directly accessed from the Internet.

You would need to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance in the public subnet and, from there, connect to the RDS database. For example, you could **use SSH with Port Forwarding**. This will keep your database secure without exposing it to the Internet.